# Add scene when build Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

When I build Unity project I saw that if I add current scene Unity or not the game still run fine.
So what is the purpose of add scene ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not added any scenes then unity will build with your current opened scene by default. The purpose of adding scene is to handle among multiple scenes like Main Menu, Store, Gameplay, Gameover etc. To get more than one scene, you have to add all the relevant scenes, otherwise unity will not recognise the scene when you want to switch to another scene.

Answer (score 1):

As long as @Hamza Hasan answer is correct, I think that question author means something diffrent.

He asks why he should add scene if it works fine in Editor without this action.

So the answer is, if this scene is not first default one (and it is your case), you wont be able to load it programaticaly, as it wasnt included into build even if it works in Editor. It works in Editor couse it was loaded into memory opening the scene.